# Escape react-router scope

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router in my application. I have a facebook link
    . But clicking on it, will append the link to my localhost as localhost:3000/www.facebook.com. How do I make it such that it goes out of react-router's scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please specify the HTTP or HTTPS protocol with www

Please use like below if you are getting the URL from context or state:

```
<a href={this.context.myurl} target="_top">Facebook</a>
<a href={this.state.myurl} target="_top">Facebook</a>
```

use `target="_blank"` in case you want to open it in a new tab.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Link` from `react-router` to open external link. Just try

```
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

**UPD**
You can find useful wrappers for links there - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147

Comment: I am using <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a> itself

Comment: @CKA Have you tried to add protocol? like `href="https://facebook.com"`